# objective c - NSDictionary to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I have NSDictionary *jsonDict2 data structured as shown below:

> {"success":true,"terms":"https://currencylayer.com/terms","privacy":"https://currencylayer.com/privacy","timestamp":1446762908,"source":"USD","quotes":{"USDAED":3.67295,"USDAFN":65.059998,"USDALL":127.794502,"USDAMD":476.320007,"USDANG":1.790285,"USDAOA":135.210495,"USDARS":9.56045,

Which I need to populate an array with - I am doing this with below code:

```
NSArray *CurrencyArray = [jsonDict2 objectForKey:@"quotes"];
```

which populates an array:
    USDAED = "3.67295";
    USDAFN = "65.05999799999999";
    USDALL = "127.794502";
    USDAMD = "476.320007";
    USDANG = "1.790285";
    USDAOA = "135.210495";

but I don't want values in an array (only for example: USDAED;USDAFN;USDALL...)

once I'll have that array then I need something to extract specific value selected in that array. For example for array value USDANG I need to extract value for it from *jsonDict2 dictionary (I will use picker for selecting value in an array and value from dictionary will be displayed in a label)

Answer (score 1):

You need to carefully pay attention to your types.

The value of "quotes" is not an array, it's another dictionary.

If you want to extract just the keys of the dictionary as an array, use the allKeys method. To extract just the values of a dictionary as an array, use the allValues method.

Answer (score 0):

the "quotes" is a dictionary,not a array

if you want to get NSArray,you must convert it manual

```
NSMutableArray *CurrencyArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *CurrencyValueArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDictionary *CurrencyDict = [jsonDict2 objectForKey:@"quotes"];
for (NSString *key in CurrencyDict) {
    [CurrencyArray addObject:key];
    [CurrencyValueArray addObject:[CurrencyDict valueForKey:key]];
}
```

Comment: Why bother with the `for` loop? Just use the `allKeys` and `allValues` methods of `NSDictionary`.

Comment: you are right,i knew these two method,but i just want to told about this json's structure,may be have some action in this loop